# Enable/disable check constraint in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Is it possible to temporarily enable/disable check constraints in Teradata DB? If yes, please how?

Thanks.

Comment: no you have to DROP and after you do whatever you want ADD the constraint again

Comment: Take a look at: https://support.teradata.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=a1c6c7ef1b57fb00682ca8233a4bcb97